# How to view partial results in spatialite-gui?

Tags: sqlite, spatialite

I'm running a query to create a table using the spatialite gui on my Windows 7 machine. It has been going for days and I would like to cancel it and try something different. Is there a way for me to view the results of the query so far? The .sqlite file has trippled in size and I'm curious about what is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQLite, transactions are atomic and isolated. (And if you do not use explicit transactions, every command gets an automatic transaction.)

So there is no easy way to see partial results; the database goes to great efforts to ensure that the transaction either succeeds completely, or is rolled back.

If possible, try the command with a smaller data set, or write the query so that only a part of the data is processed.